# Using buttons within mapped details throws error "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a basic page in which I retrieve a bunch of details from my back end and displays to my front end by mapping it.

This works completely fine however when I try and put a button in one (along with binding it and creating a handler) it keeps throwing below error.

```
Error: ManageWorkstations(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I understand this is thrown when something is not returned but how come simply creating a button with functionally causes this?

Below is my full code for the mapped object (with button with `onClick` still included).

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import AddWorkstation from "./UpdateUserWorkStationDetailsForm";
class ManageWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { AccountDetails: [] };
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  getItems() {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("User");
    if (user) {
      fetch(`/profile-work-station-detailss/${user}`)
        .then(recordset => recordset.json())
        .then(results => {
          this.setState({ AccountDetails: results.recordset });
        });
    } else {
      alert("user not  set");
    }
  }
  //when the component mounts make the sql questions the
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      AccountDetails: this.getItems()
    });
  }

  handleDelete(e) {
    alert("pohfspuidhfg");
  }

  render() {
    try {
      return (
        <>
          <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            {" "}
            <u>Manage Work Stations</u>
          </h3>
          {this.state.AccountDetails ? (
            <ul>
              <Link to="/profile">
                <button style={{ float: "left" }} className="btn btn-secondary">
                  Account Details
                </button>
              </Link>
              <button
                style={{ float: "left" }}
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                disabled
              >
                Manage Work Stations
              </button>

              <DisplayAddWorkstation />

              <br />
              <br />

              {this.state.AccountDetails &&
                this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(AccountDetails, index) {
                  return (
                    <div className="jumbotron">
                      <button
                        style={{ float: "right" }}
                        className="btn btn-secondary"
                        onClick={this.handleDelete}
                      >
                        x
                      </button>
                      <h3>Work Station</h3>

                      <li>
                        Desk Location:
                        {AccountDetails.DeskLocation}
                      </li>

                      <li>
                        Additional Information:
                        {AccountDetails.ExtraInformation}
                      </li>

                      <li>
                        Date Added:
                        {AccountDetails.DateAdded}
                      </li>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <ul>
              <DisplayAddWorkstation />
              <br />
              <br />
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  style={{ float: "right" }}
                >
                  X
                </button>
                <h3>Work Station</h3>

                <li>
                  <div>Desk Location:</div> Null
                </li>

                <li>
                  <div>Additional Information:</div>
                  Null
                </li>

                <li>
                  <div> Date Added:</div> Null
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          )}
        </>
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The button which causes the issue is within the second return using the handler **`handleDelete`**

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT

This is the line of code which is causing the error

```
this.setState({ AccountDetails: results.recordset });
```

as soon as the onClick method is deleted (not bind or handler) the page loads again fine.

Comment: You have a try catch around your render function, if it hits the catch block then nothing is being rendered. I suspect you may have another exception being caught and logged. After logging from your catch what happens if you then `return null;`

Comment: Furthermore to Expired Data's comment, <DisplayAddWorkstation /> is not defined, that could be your error that is being caught in the catch statement.

Comment: Charlie That is not the case thanks for the advice. That component is actually defined within the same file.

Comment: @ExpiredData when in my catch I returned null it did not return any of the mapped object just the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to return something in your `catch` statement:

```
catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but this simply but this creates another issue of none of the mapped objects being displayed so the page only consists of the header.

Comment: That's because you have a generic try/catch block. If any error is thrown it immediately renders the catch block. I would recommend you remove the try/catch and handle errors individually.

Comment: Thanks! Now I receive a different error which should be easier to solve.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDelete' of undefined

Comment: Which line number is the error coming from? Can you show updated code?